# SQL : combine 2 statements with 2 SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

How can I combine these 2 SQL statement into a one?

I would like to replace the value `shape` here:

```
SELECT path[1] AS number, st_x(geom), st_y(geom) 
FROM st_dumppoints(shape)
```

by this :

```
SELECT shape 
FROM tableA 
WHERE id = 'test'
```

Something like this:

```
SELECT path[1] AS number, st_x(geom), st_y(geom) 
FROM st_dumppoints(SELECT shape FROM tableA WHERE id = 'test')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an extra pair of parentheses around the subselect. Syntactically, a subquery needs parentheses, and the function invocation too, so you end up with

```
FROM st_dumppoints((SELECT shape FROM tableA WHERE id = 'test'))
```

Note that the statement will cause an error if the subquery returns more than one row.